# Objective-C String Extract Issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I am trying to figure out how to exact a certain part of a NSString, I looked at the API, but I can't seem to get the right combination of methods to do this.

I can go through each character and accomplish this, but i'm sure this is an easier way.

I have a string like this:

```
NSString *temp = @"1.09 Units";
```

I wan to extract just the Units part, so I want to end up with a String of just Units.  I am looking for a way that's universal so it won't matter of how many words in front of Units or if Units is a longer word.

So I thought of looking for the " " space between the words, but haven't had any success.

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: It might be helpful to get more examples of the types of strings you want to split apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idea :**

- Split the string, using `' ' (space)` as the delimiter
- Store it in an array. The 2nd element is what you want.

**Code :**

```
- (NSString*)getSecondPartFrom:(NSString*)str
{
     NSArray* arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
     return (NSString*)[arr objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: How did I not see that method componentsSeparatedByString?  Seriously Apple's documentation is  not my friend.

Comment: @Vikings Cocoa functions... Oh, there are so many of them, you'll most likely keep coming across new ones all the time! ;-)

Comment: It would be better to use `[arr objectAtIndex:[arr length] - 1]`. That way you will always get the last item in the array, which would matter if the string was "1 of 2 Units" or anything with more than one space.

Comment: Or – continuing on the theme of methods you haven’t heard of – `[arr lastObject]`. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use ComponentSeparated NSString method.